# SAS proc sql inside %macro that use existing data set

Tags: sql, macros, sas, proc

I have the following macro:

```
%macro AgregateSummAll(SAll,SNatl);
proc sql;
    create table &SNatl as
    select 
      Month, 
      Processing, 
      InsuranceRng,
      sum(Transactions) as Transactions, 
      sum(TotalRev) as TotalRev format dollar16.2
    from &SAll
    group by 
      Month, 
      Processing, 
      InsuranceRng;
quit;
%mend; * AgregateSumAll;
```

Inside of the program I am using existing table SumAllReg, to go through macro but SAS does not see it.
%AgregateSummAll(&SumAllReg,SumNatlReg);

Get the following error message:

> &SumAllReg
>           -
>           22
>           200 WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference SUMALLREG not resolved.

Comment: How did you define `&sumallreg`. It works fine in a test case for me.

Comment: Try adding a double `&&` to pass table name into macro.

Comment: I agree with Reeza, it works for me too. I can't replicate your error. Try testing with %LET statement to predefine your macro variable. Could it be a scope issue?

Answer (score 0):

You write `SumAllReg` is a table, not a macro variable containing the name of a table, then why did you put the `&` in `%AgregateSummAll(&SumAllReg,SumNatlReg);`? Just pass the name of the table to your macro:

```
%AgregateSummAll(SumAllReg,SumNatlReg);
```